# Variables not updating c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# Program to display the average grades, highest grade and lowerst grade

The result is supposed to be
the highest grade is 90.5
the lowerst grade is 77.3
the average grade is 85.633

But unfortunately show up like this
the highest grade is 1.7976931348623157E+308
the lowerst grade is -1.7976931348623157E+308
the average grade is 85.633

I had two days looking for a solution, but I couldn't, so I had to ask a question

Thank u

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{
    public class Statistics
    {
        public double Average;
        public double High;
        public double Low;
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {
            grades = new List<double>();
        }
        public void addGrade(double grade)
        {
            grades.Add(grade);
        }
        public Statistics GetStatistics()
        {
            var result = new Statistics();
            result.Average = 0.0;
            result.High = double.MaxValue;
            result.Low = double.MinValue;

            foreach (var grade in grades)
            {
                result.Low = Math.Min(grade, result.Low);
                result.High = Math.Max(grade, result.High);
                result.Average += grade;
            }
            result.Average /= grades.Count;
            return result;
        }
        private List<double> grades;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.addGrade(89.1);
            book.addGrade(90.5);
            book.addGrade(77.3);
            var stats = book.GetStatistics();

            Console.WriteLine("the highest grade is " + stats.High);
            Console.WriteLine("the lowerst grade is " + stats.Low);
            Console.WriteLine($"the average grade is {stats.Average:N3}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest defining fields at the top of a file, as this is how it's commonly done. It caused a moment's confusion as to where `grades` was defined.

Comment: the `Low` will never be lower than `MinValue` and similarly  for `Max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assgigned `double.MaxValue` to the High score and `double.MinValue` to the low.

So when you use `Math.max / Math.min` you are  constantly getting the double.Max / double.Min.

try to just switch them in the following way (will only work assuming values are provided)  :

```
result.High = double.MinValue;
result.Low = double.MaxValue;
```

Comment: I did condition the solution with having values, to begin with. I would include a condition before - if there are not values return hight = 0, low = 0 and average = 0 (no need for arithmetic)

Comment: I'm watching course on pluralsight. He wrote the code like yours, but I didn't focus, so I reversed it! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this code to evaluate each grade against the variables `result.Low` and `result.High` outside of the loop:

```
result.Low = Math.Min(grade, result.Low);
result.High = Math.Max(grade, result.High);
```

But you have defined them as this:

```
result.High = double.MaxValue;
result.Low = double.MinValue;
```

Therefore it isn't possible for `grade > double.MaxValue`, or `grade < double.MinValue`

A better solution is this:

```
var result = new Statistics();
var firstGrade = grades.DefaultIfEmpty().First(); // get the first grade in the list, or 0 if it's empty

// assign that to average, high, and low
result.Average = firstGrade;
result.High = firstGrade;
result.Low = firstGrade;

// visit every grade after the first
foreach (var grade in grades.Skip(1))
{
    result.Low = Math.Min(grade, result.Low);
    result.High = Math.Max(grade, result.High);
    result.Average += grade;
}

result.Average /= grades.Count;
return result;
```

We should also consider the case that `grades.Count == 0`, which would throw an error on the `result.Average  /= grades.Count` line. We can fix it like so:

```
if (grades.Count > 0)
{
    result.Average /= grades.Count;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping `result.High` to `double.MinValue` and `result.Low` to `double.MaxValue` should do the trick!

Comment: Until `grades` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you've mixed `double.MaxValue and`double.MinValue` around. Alternatively you could avoid them entirely by doing this:

```
public Statistics GetStatistics()
{
    return new Statistics()
    {
        Average = grades.Average(),
        High = grades.Max(),
        Low = grades.Min(),
    };
}
```